# Entropy of Input to N Parallel BSC's Given the Output

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Given the N noisy observations $Y_{1:N}$ of a length-$L$ binary input sequence X passed through N parallel BSC's with the same crossover probability $p$, what is the entropy of the input sequence:
\begin{equation}
H(X|Y_{1:N})
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has an explicit nice solution. Let $Y_i=X+Z_i$. I suppose you mean $Z_i$ are i.i.d. random variables with distribution $Bern(\rho)$. You can write:
\begin{align*}
H(X|Y_{1:N})=&-H(Y_{1:N})+H(X,Y_{1:N})\\
=&-H(Y_{1:N})+H(X)+H(Y_{1:N}|X)\\
=&-H(Y_{1:N})+H(X)+nh_b(\rho)\\
=&-H(X+Z_1,X+Z_2,\cdots,X+Z_n)+H(X)+nh_b(\rho).
\end{align*}
However, the term $H(X+Z_1,X+Z_2,\cdots,X+Z_n)$ cannot be simplified for the general case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mini. I think there is a small typo in the sign of the $H(Y_{1:N})$ term in your expression. Seen as there seems to be no nice expression, would you have any ideas on how to find an upper bound on the mutual information $H(X) - H(X|Y_{1:N})$ for such a channel?